# Différence d'usage entre le français « épicène » et l'anglais « epicene »

Tags: anglais, usage, comparaison-de-langues

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epicene

> Definition of epicene  1 of a noun : having but one form to indicate
>   either sex 2a : having characteristics typical of the other sex b :
>   EFFEMINATE 3 : lacking characteristics of either sex

et

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne/30339

> Se dit d'un nom qui a la même forme aux deux genres, correspondant aux
>   deux sexes (par exemple un élève/une élève, un enfant/une enfant). Se
>   dit d'un nom qui peut désigner indifféremment un mâle ou une femelle
>   (par exemple la perdrix, le papillon).

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne

> ÉPICÈNE, adj. GRAMM., rare. A.− [En parlant d'un nom d'être animé]
>   (Terme générique) qui sert à désigner une espèce, sans préciser le
>   sexe. Les mots Enfant, perdrix sont des noms épicènes (Ac.1932). B.−
>   [En parlant d'un subst., d'un adj., d'un pron.] Qui a la même forme au
>   masculin et au féminin (cf. Dupré Lex. 1972). Prononc. et Orth. :
>   [episεn]. Ds Ac. 1762-1932. Étymol. et Hist. 1464 gramm. epichene «
>   qui est commun au genre masculin et féminin » (Lagadeuc, Cathol.,
>   Quimp. ds Gdf. Compl.). Empr. au lat. class.epicoenus « épicène », gr.
>   ε ̓ π ι ́ κ ο ι ν ο ς « possédé en commun, épicène ».

Pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence entre l'anglais et le français, à savoir,

> either sex 2a : having characteristics typical of the other sex b :
>   EFFEMINATE 3 : lacking characteristics of either sex

qui ne se rencontre pas en français?

Comment: Qu'en était-il en grec ? (puis en latin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attention, tout ce qui suit n'est *que* spéculation personnelle.**

Je crois que la signification particulière que donne l'anglais remonte à Ben Jonson.
Non! Pas le coureur dopé, un contemporain de Shakespeare! ;-)

Il est de fait l'auteur d'une pièce (***Epicoene or the silent woman*** ~1600.)

Or il se trouve que la dite (puisqu'au début de la pièce Épicène est censée être une femme) n'est en fait qu'un garçon travesti en femme.

Je crois pouvoir dire qu'épicène ne possède pas cette définition avant lui puisque Ben Jonson lui-même justifiera son choix du nom du personnage en écrivant : "*Epicene understands both kindes, especially when we cannot make the difference*" c'est bien à dire en rappelant la définition commune à nos deux langues amenant l'originalité de son choix.

---

NDaCOSwt : Étant donnée la nature spéculative de ces propos, merci à l'auteur de la question de ne pas l' *accepter* de sorte à ne pas lui marquer un crédit possiblement abusif.

Comment: +1 Le mot a décollé en anglais à la fin du XVIIIe siècle alors que le personnage central d'une pièce de Robert Hitchcock (pas le metteur en scène ;-) ), *The Macaroni*, 1773, est nommé *Epicene*.  Voir [Macaroni (mode)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macaroni_(fashion))

Answer (score 1):

Il n'est pas nécessairement étonnant que le Français et l'Anglais appliquent à un même mot des sens distincts à partir d'une racine commune: On sait que toute unité sémantique se transforme lentement au fil du temps, en s'enrichissant de sens nouveaux issus d'une perception imagée, ou parfois même restrictive, du sens originel: sur des territoires culturellement séparés, ces transformations finissent nécessairement par s'opérer de manière distincte.

Un des cas les plus criants de cette dérive de l'anglais par rapport au français (car jusqu'au XIXe siècle, c'est le français qui donne le ton, même si la situation s'est inversée au XXe), est celui du mot `decade` qui est une appropriation erronée du français `décade`, qui signifie "dix jours", tandis que les anglais lui ont appliqué le sens de "dix ans" qui, en français se dit `décennie`...